# How to save text to json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i want to save text to json.
this my code.

```
TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController nohap = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController tinggi = TextEditingController();
```

---

here text field.

```
TextFormField(
   controller: nohap,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
   autofocus: false,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
   hintText: 'Nomor Handphone',
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
   border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
   ),
),
```

please helpme.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should write some code that attempts to solve the problem  and come back when you have a specific coding problem to ask about.

Answer (score 1):

```
 final json = {
    'name': name.text,
    'nohap': nohap.text,
    'tinggi': tinggi.text,
  };
```